# Export atlas PDF failed to print images item on template

Tags: qgis, image, atlas, template, atlas-generator

I create a template on QGIS which contains some text and images. I render the image using HTML with code:

```
    <style>
.cropped {
    position: absolute;
    width: 27mm; /* width of container */
    height: 27mm;
    background-size: 256px  144px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#jpg {    background-image: url('img/[%"photo"%]');

}
</style>
<div>
<div class="cropped" id="jpg"></div>
<div>
```

The atlas has more than 10K items, when I tried to export the atlas on the folder, most of the images failed to be print on the PDF export file. But if I tried to add images without HTML, it works good on exporting. But actually I will need HTML styling version to print the atlas. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a timing issue of Qt. The PDF generation is faster than the HTML rendering. Whenever I face such problems (missing images in HTML, missing SVGs, partly rendered images, Javascript processing in HTML), I'm using a custom Python "wait" function to pause the printing process.

Put the following Python code in the "*Python Macros*" section of your project (Project > Properties... > Macros) and enable running macros (Settings > Options > General):

```py
from qgis.core import qgsfunction
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QTimer,QEventLoop
@qgsfunction(args=1, group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referenced_columns=[])
def waitX(values, feature, parent):
    x = values[0]
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(x,loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    return 0
```

To get the HTML completely rendered, you have to inject this expression function somewhere into the printing process. I always put it into the data defined override of the label or HTML item Rendering exclusion option (Rendering > Exclude item from exports). That's why this function returns "0". You have to play with the function argument to increase or decrease sleeping time depending on the content of your HTML.

[image]

Comment: Hi christoph, thanks for your response. I'm trying to running and add function ```waitX(300)``` on rendering options, but the expression was not recognized on string builder windows (Expression is invalid). do you know why?

Comment: You have to reopen your QGIS project after putting the Python code into the Macro section. And take care that running macros is enabled. You will find waitX inside Custom functions.

Comment: Cool, it works now. Now I'm trying to play with this function. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If the answer has met your expectations, you should mark it as „accepted“.

Comment: Is there maximum time for the function? I could not add more than ```10000```, although ```10000```` still not running my atlas successfully

Comment: Don't think it's a problem with the time value. The msec parameter of QTimer.singleShot takes integer values. So I guess the max value should be 2,147,483,647. Do you get your HTML correctly rendered in Layout?

Comment: the rendering proses works fine, and when trying again with 30s, it works if I export the atlas in one single file, but still not working (not printing the image) if I export the file separately. do you know why this could happen?