# QGIS Atlas generate QR code from map center does not refresh automatically

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QR-Codes generated dynamically inside an HTML element on the atlas-maps in QGIS. The map has the id:map2 and the QR-code gives the quickest route to this place using Google Maps. This works fine, but in an atlas sometimes the QR-code does not reflect the actual map center, it stays with the QR-code of the former map, so that users are dirrected to the wrong place.

Is there a way to force QGIS to do a refresh of the HTML-code after the map has changed?
Here the code I use inside the HTML element (the project SRID is EPSG:3857 and it needs to be transformed to EPSG:4326 for Google Maps):

```
<img src = 
"[% 'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=350x350&margin=5&data=url_quote
(''https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fdir%2F%3Fapi%3D1%26basemap%3Dsatellite%26destination%3D'
||y(transform(map_get( item_variables( 'map2'), 'map_extent_center' ),'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')) 
||'%2C' 
||x(transform(map_get( item_variables( 'map2'), 'map_extent_center' ),'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'))%]"
style="width: auto; height: 100%; display: block; margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;"
/>
```

Even with the 'QR Barcode Layout Item' from the QGIS Plugins Repository I had this issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing that QGIS does not refresh the HTML-code, during the preview in map layouts itself or when you export to raster/pdf?

Comment: I guess it's a similar timing problem as here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326090/qgis-beautiful-html-javascript-terrain-profiles-wont-show-in-atlas-print or here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424144/export-atlas-pdf-failed-to-print-images-item-on-template

Answer (score 0):

You could create a QGIS Python Expression function and call it inside a HTML label.

Install the Python library `qrcode` first:
`pip install qrcode`

```py
import qrcode
import base64
from io import BytesIO

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[], usesgeometry=False)
def makeQR(url, width, feature, parent):
    """
    Create a QR-Code HTML image
    <h2>Example usage:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>makeQR('https://www.qgis.org','150px')</li>
      <li><img style="width:150px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/></li>
    </ul>
    """
    image = qrcode.make(url)
    buffered = BytesIO()
    image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
    img = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode('UTF-8')
    html = f'<img width="{width}" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{img}"/>'
    return html
```

[image]